# tmux bash command unresponsive

Tags: tmux, remote

I'm on a remote host and when I type `tmux` the command executes without throwing an error however does not open the standard tmux window. Instead, nothing appears to happen. The behaviour is the same when I run `tmux ls`. However illegal tmux commands, e.g. `tmux -z` give the following error as expected when it is working normally.

```bsh
$ tmux -z
tmux: illegal option -- z
usage: tmux [-2CluvV] [-c shell-command] [-f file] [-L socket-name]
            [-S socket-path] [command [flags]]
```

I have also noticed that `man tmux` also operates in an expected way.

The issue began when ran the command `pkill -f tmux` on the remote host hoping to kill all the tmux sessions I had running. Perhaps it is useful information that I do not have a root access to the host and also that there are several other users on the host who also use tmux. When I ran `pkill -f tmux` I got permission denied to kill a number of processes which I assume they were running in tmux. How can I fix this issue so tmux behaves normally again?

Comment: Is `tmux` server running for your user? Can you kill it forcefully? See `man 1 tmux` for `-v` option. Run a valid command with the option, so the issue is triggered; abort and examine the log(s). [Edit] the question and paste what looks relevant.

Comment: The problem seems to have automatically resolved itself without any change. This is very strange but means I can't reproduce the issue. Should I delete the question or leave it up?